# Ошибка синтаксиса при вставке данных в БД

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Никак не пойму где я ошибаюсь.
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''persons' VALUES ('123', dfgh, kkk, 33)' at line 1**

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 'persons' VALUES ($idInput, $nameInput,        
 $lnameInput, $ageInput)" , $db) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: `"INSERT INTO persons VALUES ('$idInput', '$nameInput',        
 '$lnameInput', '$ageInput')"`

Comment: @Doofy вокруг числовых значений кавычки не нужны, при вставке множества данных (допустим, 50мб и больше) они *реально* мешают и чем меньше длина вставляемого значения, тем больше оверхед.

Comment: @strangeqargo, а если в структуре таблицы integer записывается в varchar?

Comment: @Doofy ну, если того требует структура таблицы, конечно да, но лучше стараться такого избегать. Если поле логина принимает и цифры и буквы, то да, но числовое поле - лучше нет (если сам руками запросы пишешь, а не orm)

Comment: @strangeqargo, это надо добавить в ответ. Тоесть если в структуре поля должен входить integer, кавычки не нужны для числа

Answer (score 2, accepted):

кавычки вокруг строковых значений кто будет проставлять?
и поставьте MySQL Workbench, он автоматически подсвечивает строку с некорректным синтаксисом, в нем и дебажьте ваши запросы

p.s. и у вас еще одна ошибка (первопричина, кстати) - одинарные кавычки вокруг имени таблицы

```
mysql> use 'db'; #здесь корректно, но излишне, это внутренняя команда mysql
# хотя use db тоже сработает (и быстрее печатать)
Database changed
mysql> show tables;
+--------------+
| Tables_in_db |
+--------------+
| OrderHistory |
| users        |
+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
#здесь некорректно, не по стандарту SQL
mysql> select * from 'users';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users'' at line 1
```

во первых, в этом запросе кавычки вокруг имени таблицы не нужны, а во вторых, правильные кавычки для sql - это backticks:

```
mysql> select * from `users`;
+----+------------+-
| id | login
```

ответ к комменту
касательно кавычек вокруг полей типа INT/DOUBLE/FLOAT  и т.д.: они возможны, но не обязательны. При малой нагрузке лишний байтик потраченный на передачу кавычек незаметен.

При большой нагрузке, при вставке больших объемов данных (когда вы вставляете данные вплоть до `max_allowed_packet`) , когда у вас идет множество числовых полей, вы получите дополнительную нагрузку/придется снизить количество рядов, которые вы можете вставить одновременнно.

Кроме того, чисто семантически это дает понять, когда вы просматриваете какой-нибудь большой запрос, что цифры должны вставляться в колонку с числовым типом.

Когда вы видите такой запрос, вы понимаете, что в этом есть логика и намерение.

Comment: ` - это правильные кавычки только для MySQL! Для SQL стандарт - "users". В MySQL по-умолчанию отключены, включаются через ANSI_QUOTES в sql_mode

Comment: спасибо за уточнение